# What does it mean to see same God again and again in different situations in dream?

Tags: gods, dream

From different Vedantic explanation, I have learnt that the same consciousness changes its form from a waking body to a dreamer body. So, it seems to me like, if God can incarnate in real-world and meet people to teach them the truth, then he can really appear to a dreamer(please correct me if I'm wrong).

If someone seeing the same God, again and again, every time the story is different. Was it something created by the mind of the dreamer? I don't know if it is ok to share the spiritual experience, please ask me if I need to clarify it. Please guide me. Thanks.

*Note*: This question is not the same as [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/does-seeing-the-same-dream-several-times-indicate-something) one. I am asking about a situation when every time God is the same, but every time the story is different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does seeing the same dream several times indicate something?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/does-seeing-the-same-dream-several-times-indicate-something)

Comment: Do not ask personal questions. Also, when someone fixates on a certain subject the dreams are naturally occurring. Some goes for example for mathmaticians or poets.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I am not asking about seeing the same thing every time, but seeing the same God every time the story is different.

Comment: @Wikash_ I will try to remove the personal details.

Comment: a person who has had the vision of God in a dream is known as a svapnasiddha.